# Using ARToolkit with android

Tags: android, artoolkit

A project is assigned to me, in which i need to use **ARToolKit**. But i am much confused on how to use it, how to get started with **ARToolKit**.

Is it the same as **metaio**, **vuforia** and **total immersion** ? Please help me get started with it. I would be thankful to start if some startup tutorials and sample examples on ARToolKit is provided..

Any kind of help would appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the ARToolkit demo provided on Google Code which might guide you [Check Out](https://code.google.com/p/andar/)

Also check out the documentation [here](https://jira.ai2.upv.es/confluence/download/attachments/12222485/WGM16_ARToolKit.pdf)

Comment: Thanks. I'll go through it. One thing i had to ask is that, is it same as metaio, vuforia, or total immersion ? Or a different thing.

Comment: Yes its similar to this only. '

Answer (score 2):

**For Android**:

You can give a try  to droidAR
[droidAR](https://github.com/bitstars/droidar)

**For iOS**
You can give a try to VRToolkit.This app uses ARToolKit plus to detect markers on the video frames and then overlays 3D objects following the movements of this marker.

You can scan all 4096 BCH marker as well as thin based Marker after setting corresponding property to YES.

[VRToolKit github](https://github.com/benlodotcom/VRToolKit)

Comment: Thanks... I was aware about droidAR but VRToolkit is new to me. I'll go thru it today itself.